# Ansible invoke-sqlcmd fails with Invoke-Sqlcmd : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt \r\nfunctionality is not available

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, ansible

I'm trying to run a query on a remote SQL server instance using ansible to 
invoke-sqlcmd. It fails on one of the instance to execute and return results.
On all others runs with no errors.

No idea if this is an issue with Ansible or powershell or SQL Server to let ansible query through win-shell.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: kerberos ticket for individual svc account
      include_tasks: dbserveraudit_kerbinit.yml
      vars:
        ansible_user: "{{ hostvars[item]['svc_user'] }}"
      with_items: "{{ groups['current_sqlservers'] }}"

- hosts: management
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Test sql Connection using svc account
      include_tasks: **dbserveraudit_checksqlconnectivity**.yml
      vars:
        ansible_user: "{{ hostvars[item]['svc_user']  }}@{{admin_domain | upper }}"
        sqlserver: "{{ hostvars[item]['svc_user'] | regex_replace('svc','') }}"
      with_items: "{{ groups['current_sqlservers'] }}"
```

### **dbserveraudit_checksqlconnectivity.yml**

```
- block:
    - name: Connect and run query on current db server
      win_shell: Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')" -ServerInstance {{ sqlserver }} -Verbose -OutputSqlErrors 1 -AbortOnError -querytimeout 65335 -Debug 
      register: connectsql
      ignore_errors: true
```

**Error** I get is-

> "Invoke-Sqlcmd : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read
>   and Prompt \r\nfunctionality is not available.\r\nAt line:1
>   char:65\r\n+ [Console]::InputEncoding = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding
>   $false; \r\nInvoke-Sqlcmd -Q ...\r\n+
>
> ```
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (US02PRDSQL271B:PSObject) [Invoke \r\n   -Sqlcmd], PSInvalidOperationException\r\n    +
> FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.P \r\n  
> owerShell.GetScriptCommand",
> ```

Comment: Posting the errors and command you use would be really useful here. It's really hard to debug code when you don't have said code, or the error the code is generating.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for pointing it out. So we have a playbook that calls a taskbook in loop. Have added both the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Verbosity uses interactive outputs. Pipe the output to a log file or NUL:
Tip: Infinite querytimeout is: 0 ;)
Try:

```
$Log: "c:\temp\test.txt"
(Invoke-SqlCmd -query "Select 1" -Verbose -OutputSqlErrors 1 -AbortOnError -querytimeout 0 -Debug) *>> $Log
```